# Regroup common rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a query that will give me 4 duplicates **everytime** because **one** field is different.

Let's say I have this table

```
-----------------
| A |  B | C | D |
-----------------
| 1 |Blue| 2 | 0 |
| 1 |Blue| 2 | 1 |
| 1 |Blue| 2 | 2 |
| 1 |Blue| 2 | 3 |
| 2 |Red | 1 | 0 |
| 2 |Red | 1 | 1 |
| 2 |Red | 1 | 2 |
| 2 |Red | 1 | 3 |
------------------
```

What I would like to do is regroup them into one. As for the `D` column they should be grouped into one using `SUM()`.

The thing is I don't know where to start. Is there a keyword to group them into one ? I would have used `Distinct` but I will still have 4 of them because of 1 mismatch.

The final reuslt set should be

```
------------------
| A |  B | C | D |
------------------
| 1 |Blue| 2 | 6 |
| 2 |Red | 1 | 6 |
------------------
```

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

sure it's possible -- this should do it:

```
 select A, B, C, sum(D) as D
 from TABLE
 group by A, B, C
```